# Python 3.5: Sublime Text Won't Recognize 3rd Party Modules...How to Fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, sublimetext3

(I understand variations of this question have been asked before, but not specifically with Python 3+ and Sublime Text 3, and I tried the solutions but none of them worked.)

Anyhow: I'm using Python 3.5. I'm trying to use a 3rd party module - Scrapy - in Sublime Text. While the module works in IDLE, it does not work in Sublime.

I tried redirecting my `PYTHONPATH` but that still didn't work. My syntax-specific settings for Python are:

```
{
        "path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
        "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "selector": "source.python",
        "word_wrap": true, 
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this.

In your case Sublime Text 3.x needs a new build system that needs the "path" and the "cmd" defined in the new build system to correctly recognize **both** the location of the modules and what python command string you want to build with.

For Python 3.7 on OSX 10.14.2 I used the build file below. I assume the same will work with 3.5 or any 3.x version if modified by replacing the 3.7's with 3.5's. If you install a new version of python you will need a new build system in sublime as well.

Under tools>build system>new build system add a file containing the settings below and save it.

```
{
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
    "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Switch to it using tools > build with.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html), not syntax-specific settings. Select **`Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...`** and change the contents to the following:

```
{
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
    "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save the file as `Packages/User/Python3.5.sublime-build` where `Packages` is the folder opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** (when you hit Save after editing the new build system, it should automatically point you to `Packages/User`).

To use the build system, select **`Tools -> Build System -> Python3.5`**, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (Windows, Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (OS X) when your `.py` file is focused.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - any suggestions for improvement would be helpful...